# update names based on columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like update the names based on two columns

My example has 3 originial columns

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", 'a', NA, NA, NA),
                 name2 = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "c", NA, NA, NA),
                 name3 = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"))

df
  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     a
7  <NA>  <NA>     a
8  <NA>  <NA>     a
```

I would like to update column `name3` (or even create a new column) saying that if `name1` == `a`, and `name2` == `NA`, then the `a` character in `name3` will be replaced by `b` in column `name2`.

My desired output something like

```
  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     b
7  <NA>  <NA>     b
8  <NA>  <NA>     b
```

So far, i am using this `df %>% mutate(name3 = ifelse(name1 == "a" & is.na(name2), "b", name3))`, but now `NA` appeared. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: In your expected output `name1 == "a"` is `FALSE`, both `name1` and `name2` are `NA`, why has `name3` changed?

Comment: I just wanted to change the `b` in `name3` based on the condition that I want from `name1` and `name2`. Since the real dataset is so messy, so I want to split several cases that I think would be nice to solve. Thats why I call `a` and NA from name1 and name2 respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Base R

```
df$name3 <- ifelse(any(df$name1 == "a") & is.na(df$name2), "b", df$name3)
```

### `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = case_when(
    any(name1 == "a") & is.na(name2) ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ name3
  ))
#  name1 name2 name3
#1     a     b     b
#2     a     b     b
#3     a     b     b
#4     a     b     b
#5     a     c     c
#6  <NA>  <NA>     b
#7  <NA>  <NA>     b
#8  <NA>  <NA>     b
```

Comment: Many thanks for the `any`!

Comment: anyway, thank you to provide your answer. It worked well, sir.

Answer (score 2):

We can replace `==` with `%in%` to eliminate the NAs, because R evaluates `NA %in% x` to FALSE, but `NA==x` to NA

```
df %>% mutate(name3 = ifelse(name1 %in% 'a' & is.na(name2), 'b', name3))
```

Comment: I think it was at same time.+1

Comment: Timmed to the exact same second! +1

Comment: yes, and the outcome taking `a` not `b` is not our expectation, right

Answer (score 2):

We could use a `case_when` or `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = case_when(any(name1 %in% "a") &
                             is.na(name2) ~ "b",
                           TRUE ~ name3))

or:
df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = ifelse(any(name1 %in% "a") & 
                          is.na(name2), "b", name3))
```

```
  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     b
7  <NA>  <NA>     b
8  <NA>  <NA>     b
```

Comment: I  think the output is `b` will compensate for `a` instead right

Comment: Please see my update!