# update names based on columns R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Following this question ([update names based on columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531426/update-names-based-on-columns/69531500?noredirect=1#comment122899627_69531500)), another thing that I want to ask

```
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", 'a', NA, NA, NA,NA),
                 name2 = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "c", NA, NA, NA,NA),
                 name3 = c("b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a", "f"))

df
  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     a
7  <NA>  <NA>     a
8  <NA>  <NA>     a
9  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

Now, I want to keep `f` while replacing `a` by `b`.

-Desired output

```
  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     b
7  <NA>  <NA>     b
8  <NA>  <NA>     b
9  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

The code from comments of @Rui and @TarJae

```
df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = case_when(
    any(name1 == "a") & is.na(name2) ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ name3
  ))
```

However, in this case, this does not work because I call `NA` from `name2`.
Any sugesstions for me?

Comment: Do you just want to change the values of `names3` from `a` to `b`?

Comment: yes, the idea is to change `a` to `b`, but the replacement should based on some conditions, like that

Comment: The code provided from @Tjn25 works and provides the expected output that you have shown. You should provide a better explanation or better example to demonstrate what exactly you want to do rather than explaining in comments later.

Comment: yes, that was a big ambiguous from my side. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: The question is not clear, so what for example means "this post" and "came up from my question"?

Comment: @tpetzoldt thank for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to keep `f`, how about this?

**edit** except `a` and `b` will be not be changed.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(name3 = case_when(
    !(name3 %in% c("a", "b")) ~ name3,
    any(name1 == "a") & is.na(name2) ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ name3
  ))


  name1 name2 name3
1     a     b     b
2     a     b     b
3     a     b     b
4     a     b     b
5     a     c     c
6  <NA>  <NA>     b
7  <NA>  <NA>     b
8  <NA>  <NA>     b
9  <NA>  <NA>     f
```

Comment: ...what if I have many rows contain `f`, `e`, so on, then this code does nt solve it right?

Comment: @Anh Do you want to keep `f`, `e` that's not `a` or `b`? May I ask the exact conditions of `name3` to keep?

Comment: I mean the `name3` column could have more different values like `f` or `e`, and so on. Then calling `f` is not a good ideal option.

Comment: @Anh That's why I asked for condition. If anything else without `a` and `b` will not be changed, I edit code above.

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing the solution @Tjn25, one can do the following

```r
f <- function(x) ifelse(x == "a", "b", x)

data.frame(lapply(df, f))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change the `names3` column values that are `a` to `b`
then you could use

```
df$name3[df$name3 == 'a'] <- 'b'
```

Comment: not what I want, but still thanks any